# Store variable in a for loop with concatenated column

Tags: r

I'm doing a rpois simulation and I want to create a function to automate variable change (lambda).

My function should be able to change the lambda value. For example, here I want to change three variables `n1` (175), `n2` (11) and `n3` (14)
and the number of poison random depending on the number of row of the concatenate input data frame like in my example.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
library(broom)
set.seed(12358)

pois_1 <- tidy(summary(as.factor(rpois(n = 1000000, lambda = (1/336981)*175*11*14)))/1000000)
pois_2 <- tidy(summary(as.factor(rpois(n = 1000000, lambda = (1/336981)*500*11*14)))/1000000)
pois_3 <- tidy(summary(as.factor(rpois(n = 1000000, lambda = (1/336981)*900*11*14)))/1000000)

df_info <- data.frame(pois_1[1:5, ], pois_2[1:5, 2], pois_3[1:5, 2])
names(df_info) <- c("occurence", "175", 
                    "500", "900")
df_info %>%
  gather(fl, proba, "175":"900") -> df_info

ggplot(data = df_info, aes(x = fl,
                           y = proba,
                           group = occurence)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2) + 
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = ifelse(proba > 0.02, as.character(round(proba, 2)), "")),
                   box.padding   = 0.35,
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = 'grey50') +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = occurence, color = occurence), size = 1) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"))
```

Here I wanted to create a function like that with a for loop but it seems to be quite complicated:

Edit : done with only a vector but I want to do it for `n1> 1`

```
vizFun <- function(n1, n2, n3){

  df_info <- cbind(n1, n2, n3)
  names(df_info) <- c("n1", "n2", "n3")
  if (nrow(df_info) == 1){
    for (i in seq_along(nrow(df_info))){
      lambda <- (1/336981)*df_info[i,"n1"]*df_info[i, "n2"]*df_info[i, "n3"]
      pois <- tidy(summary(as.factor(rpois(n = 1000000, lambda = lambda)))/1000000)
      df_info <- data.frame(pois[, ])
      names(df_info) <- c("occurence", "175")
      df_info %>%
        gather(fl, proba, "175") -> df_info
    }

    ggplot(data = df_info, aes(x = fl,
                               y = proba,
                               group = occurence)) + 
      geom_point(size = 2) + 
      geom_label_repel(aes(label = ifelse(proba > 0.02, as.character(round(proba, 2)), "")),
                       box.padding   = 0.35,
                       point.padding = 0.5,
                       segment.color = 'grey50') +
      geom_line(aes(linetype = occurence, color = occurence), size = 1) +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
            axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
            axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) 

  }

}

vizFun(500, 11, 14)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking (at least not to me). Can you be more specific? Can you post what your input/outputs currently look like and what you'd like them to look like?

Comment: Yes, I want to automate my example with a function where the variable input n1, n2 and n3 should be the arguments. I want to generate my plot automaticly just with this argument change

Comment: I cannot see you calling `vizFun` anywhere in your code? I still don't understand what `vizFun` should actually be doing either...

Comment: Yes because this is the function I want to create :)

Comment: So currently you are making multiple objects of of `pois_x` with unique lambda values and generating a plot. What you want to do is have a function `vizFun` which generates a lambda value and generates the plot? i.e. all contained within a single function?

Comment: look the edit, i tried something simple and want generalized one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
yourfunction<-function(x=c(),seed=12358){
    set.seed(seed)
    require(tidyverse)
    require(ggrepel)
    require(broom)
    listdata<-list()
    for (i in 1:length(x)) {
        listdata[[i]]<- assign(paste("pois_",i),tidy(summary(as.factor(rpois(n = 1000000, lambda = (1/336981)*x[i]*11*14)))/1000000)[1:5,]) }

    df_info<-cbind.data.frame(occurence=as.character(rep(0:(5-1)), length(x)),fl=as.character(rep(x,each=5)) ,proba=dplyr::bind_rows(listdata)[,2])
    names(df_info)<-c("occurence" , "fl"    ,"proba")
    ggplot(data = df_info, aes(x = fl,
                        y = proba,
                        group = occurence)) + 
       geom_point(size = 2) + 
       geom_label_repel(aes(label = ifelse(proba > 0.02, as.character(round(proba, 2)), "")),
                        box.padding   = 0.35,
                        point.padding = 0.5,
                        segment.color = 'grey50') +
       geom_line(aes(linetype = occurence, color = occurence), size = 1) +
       theme_bw() +
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
             plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
             axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
             axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"))
}
yourfunction(x=c(175,500,700,900))
```